# How can you show a non-$scope variable on a page in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to add an objects properties to a page using angular, but the property I created is not a `$scope` variable. The reason my object isn't a `$scope` object is due to me using `google maps API` (I know I should be using one that is compatible with Angular...now, but I would like to see if I can get around that due to time crunch and I already have everything else working correctly). I have made `markers` and they make an `ajax call` on click to get data for the `marker`, which I then want to show on my modal. I have tried a few suggestions from another post about `$watch` to check for a change, but I seem to be implementing it wrong because it only runs once at the beginning of the application and then when the modal object is changed it does nothing. The code is as follows:

Outside of my Angular module:

```
var modal = {};

function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 28.5383, lng: -81.3792},
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoom: 15
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('You are here!');
        map.setCenter(pos);

        for (i = 0; i < globalDiscoveries.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: globalDiscoveries[i].location,
                map: map,
                title: globalDiscoveries[i].name,
                icon: {
                    url: globalDiscoveries[i].image, // url
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                },
                custom_param: globalDiscoveries[i].image
            });

            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                var image = marker.custom_param;

                $.post('/findImage', {image: image}, function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    modal.image = data[0].image;
                    modal.name = data[0].name;
                    modal.description = data[0].description;
                    modal.discoveredOn = data[0].discoveredOn;
                    console.log(modal);
                });

                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        }

      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }
```

code within Angular module (that pertains to this problem):

```
$scope.modal = $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function (modal) {
        return this.modal;
    }), function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('modal changed to ' + newVal);
    });
```

To recap, I am attempting to save the modal object (on change) to `$scope.modal` so I can use Angular to inject it into my modal. The `$scope.modal` `console.logs undefined` at the beginning of the program and then nothing else when my markers are clicked and the modal object changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined modal like this

```
var modal = {};
```

So, it is an `gloabl variable.`

You can access it in angular as it is global.

In angular,you can do like this.

```
$scope.modal = modal;
```

Now put [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) on it.

```
$scope.$watch('modal',function(newVal,oldVal){

    console.log(newVal); //here you can get new modal value;

},true)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @R.J , but using your changes my $scope.modal is still blank. The newVal has the data and I tried: 

    `$scope.modal = modal;

        $scope.$watch('modal',function(newVal,oldVal){

      console.log(newVal); //here you can get new modal value;
      $scope.modal = newVal;
      console.log($scope.modal); 

  },true) `
, but it isn't console.logging the new $scope.modal, it is still blank.

Comment: I take that back. If I open it before I change modal, it stays the same, but if I open the object after I change modal it will contain the updated modal in the console. Very strange, thanks again! :)